# CustomItemGenerator and the Page Editor

Tags: sitecore, sitecore6, page-editor

Sitecore 6.6 Update 4

We're using CustomItemGenerator 1.0 and I was using this to help build a primary navigation menu for a site.  This worked as expected and everything was rendered properly.

My problem is when I attempt to edit the menu via Page Editor;  I don't even see the menu.

I use a repeater and repeat over a list of links to include in the nav.  Due to the way the HTML was created, each `LI` element needs to have its own, specific ID ("Nav Id" Field in Sitecore) that ties into the CSS.  Code inside of my repeater's ItemDataBound event:

```
// Cast the item using CustomItemGenerator-generated class
GenericContentPageItem navItem = (GenericContentPageItem)e.Item.DataItem;

liMenuItem.ID = navItem.NavId.Rendered; // I tried "navItem.NavId" by itself as well
```

So while this renders properly in the browser, it doesn't when I'm in Page Editor:

```
<li id="<input id='fld_B72EB6696DCF41A49671972D5EA5DEB8_2163B90C08AB4A18970A7F3ECE79DCFC_en_1_f71bd37d18d146c19e222e89fcffe278_3' class='scFieldValue' name='fld_B72EB6696DCF41A49671972D5EA5DEB8_2163B90C08AB4A18970A7F3ECE79DCFC_en_1_f71bd37d18d146c19e222e89fcffe278_3' type='hidden' value=" Home?="">
```

... instead of it rendering like this:

```
<li id="Home">...</li>
```

Now, that having been said, I can change my code to not use the CustomItemGenerator and it works fine in the browser and Page Editor as follows:

```
GenericContentPageItem navItem = (GenericContentPageItem)e.Item.DataItem;

Item nav = Sitecore.Context.Database.GetItem(navItem.ID);
liMenuItem.ID = nav.Fields["Nav Id"].ToString();
```

I would like to avoid having to hardcode field names in my code, which is why I am using CustomItemGenerator.  Is there something that I'm doing wrong with my code that it doesn't want to work in Page Editor?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need the actual value out of the field regardless of if you are in the page editor or not, you want to use the `Raw` property:

```
liMenuItem.ID = navItem.NavId.Raw;
```